# Split string array and then use in between values together as as string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, split

I have this kind of string

```
K, Faint Brown
N, Very Light Brown
```

Now I need to enter this values in CSV file, as like below.

In Col1 it will be: K
In Col2 it will be: Faint
In Col3 it will be: Brown.

I have done this using split method but issue is if I need to enter value for second row then it should enter Very Light together in Col2, but it is entering only Very

So for second row in CSV it should look like this,

In Col1 it will be: K
In Col2 it will be: Very Light
In Col3 it will be: Brown.

My code is below :

```
`string[] colorvalues = prop.GetValue(item).ToString().Split(','); // Here first of all I am splitting using comma.

sw.Write(colorvalues[0] + ","); // Then in first column I am entering first char.

sw.Write(colorvalues[1] + ","); // Then in second column I am entering second char, but issue is here if it is Very Light then it is taking only Very.. But I need to enter full Very Light.

sw.Write(prop.GetValue(item).ToString().Split().Last() + ","); // At last I am entering Colour name.`
```

Comment: Are you asking "how to skip the first and the last values from an array and join the remaining once with space?" (Side note: Obviously you should not be showing code where you trying to construct CSV by hand... consider to [edit] that part out)

Comment: I want is, if in string second word is Faint then it should enter that word in one column and if it is like Very Faint then also this whole word 'Very Faint' should enter in one column,

Comment: Can strings also be just "brown" and "very very extremely dark brown"?

Comment: Till now I got only records which are like Faint Brown OR Very Faint Brown..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided and under the assumption that the row will be in the following format:

```
code, N(tone) color

eg: N, very very extremely dark brown
```

The idea is to get the code first, then the color - what we are then left is to extract the tone.

Putting it all together I have wrote this method which returns a Tuple:

```
public (string code, string tone, string color) GetCodeAndToneAndColor(string row)
{
    var splitRow = row.Split(",");
    string code = splitRow.First().Trim();
    string colorAndTone = splitRow[1];
    string color = colorAndTone.Split(" ").Last().Trim();

    int colorIndex = colorAndTone.IndexOf(color, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    string tone = colorAndTone.Substring(0, colorIndex).Trim();

    return (code, tone, color);
}
```

It can be called in the following manner:

```
var (code, tone, color) = GetCodeAndToneAndColor(row);
```

Comment: Will appreciate some feedback from negative. Giving a negative vote without explanation doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Sure. 1) Don't split the same string multiple times in the same way (like you did with `row`). Split once and assign to a variable. 2) I don't think getting an index of `color` substring and comparing strings is a good idea, especially when you split `colorAndTone` at least once anyways. It might be hard to understand why are you doing this at first glance.

Comment: I don't think you fully grasp the first split - that will only gets the code. Hence the second split. "Its not a good idea" is vague please explain. The StringComparison.Ordinal is to specify the culture. Most of your reasoning seems personal preferences - but there it goes. I personally think the code is simple to understand  -

Comment: 1) I meant `row.Split(",")`. There is no good reason to use it twice in a row, you are doing exactly the same thing. Split it once and assign the result to variable. Then use this variable to get the code (with `First()`) and the rest of the color string (with `[1]`). Also using `First()` and `[1]` doesn't seem consistent, I would recommend using an index (`[0]`) instead of 'First()' for clarity.

Comment: 2) Yeah, i thought it might cause a performance issue with large strings but i did a little test and it doesn't seem like it. But anyway, in context of "i need to get first, last strings and a string with everything in between, doesn't really matter what they are" i don't think you should be using the contents of the string (apart from separators). Especially when you already split `colorAndTone` and can use the indexes of resulting array. That would add clarity to your intentions, but yeah, it might be just my preference. Same with me preferring `Split()` over `Split(' ')` and `Split(" ")`

Comment: If you'll edit `row.Split(",")` part to use a variable, i will remove my downvote

Comment: row.Split(",") => var

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this works fine:

```
var input = @"K, Faint Brown
N, Very Light Brown";
```

```
var csv =
    from line in input.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    let parts = line.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    select $"{parts[0]},{String.Join(" ", parts[1..^1])},{parts[^1]}";
```

[image: csv]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your string format is as follows

> `A string without commas`, `Color Brightness in n words` `Color Name in 1 word`

I'll take `"N, Very Light Brown"` as an example. You can split these kind of strings this way:

```
//You can either use StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries,
//use a string with a comma and a whitespace as separator (", ")
//or use TrimStart() on the color definition part of your string
//so that you don't get the string with a whitespace at the start
var commaSplit = prop.GetValue(item).ToString().Split(", ");

//`commaSplit` now consists of 2 strings: "N" and "Very Light Brown"

//We write the first string as you did in your example
sw.Write(commaSplit[0] + ",");

//Now let's work on the second string
var colorDefinitionSplit = commaSplit[1].Split();

//colorDefinitionSplit now consists of 3 strings: "Very", "Light" and "Brown"
//or it might be 1 string (just "Brown")
//or n strings ("Very", "Very", "Very" ... "Very", "Light", "Brown")
//so we need to enter everything but the last word.

//first let's check if we even have anything except just "Brown"
if (colorDefinitionSplit.Length > 1)
{
    //if we do, we join everything except "Brown"
    //here you can use .SkipLast(1) instead of [0..^1] if you like it
    //(or not using C# 8.0 and later), result is the same
    var brightnessString = string.Join(' ', colorDefinitionSplit[0..^1]);
    sw.Write(brightnessString + ",");
}

//and all that's left to do is to write "Brown"
//same here, you can use Last() instead of [^1]
sw.Write(colorDefinitionSplit[^1] + ",");
```